# If $z$ is complex variable, how to prove $\lim _{z \rightarrow 0} z^{4} / |z|^2= 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

If $z$ is complex variable, how to prove $\lim _{z \rightarrow 0} z^{4} / |z|^2= 0$?

I have simplified to  $\lim _{z \rightarrow 0} z^{4} / z \bar{z}=\lim _{z \rightarrow 0} z^{3} / \bar{z}$

because $|z|^2=z \bar{z}$.

But how to progress? i don't see. Thanks

Comment: It converges to zero in absolute value therefore converges to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r, \theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and write

$$z=re^{i \theta}.$$

Then,  $z \to 0 $ iff $r \to 0$.

Thus, we can substitute $z=re^{i \theta}$ into the simplification that you obtained to get 
$$ \lim _{r \rightarrow 0} (re^{i \theta})^{3} / re^{-i \theta} = \lim _{r \rightarrow 0} r^2e^{4i \theta}=0.$$

I prefer this method to the *modulus method* because it is applicable to many other similar cases.

Answer (score 2):

ΗΙΝΤ

$|z^n|=|z|^n$ and $\left|\frac{z^4}{|z^2|}\right|=|z|^2$

Note that $\lim_{z \to 0}f(z)=0$ if and only if $\lim_{z \to 0}|f(z)|=0$